# Check firebase persisted data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a view controller which handles friendship requests, i have firebase persistence enabled and it stores every request perfectly so i can access to my data even without internet. I've implemented a banner which should appear every time when user receive a new friendship request (a new child node added), but the banner appears every time when view loads, not only when new child node added but every time when i call my observer function. So is there any way to check if specific node has already been cached by firebase persistence and only then decide to show banner or not? 
I thought about Core Data (or anything else) - save data from firebase locally and then check if user already had received request, but i want to know maybe there's more easy way to implement this

```
var names: [Name] = []

func fetchMyReqFriends() {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let reqFriendsRef = ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("reqFriends")
    reqFriendsRef.observe( .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let friends = snapValue?.allKeys as! [String]
        for each in friends {
            ref.child("users").child(each).child("profile").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let friendPage = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let snapUsername = friendPage?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                let snapFullname = friendPage?["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
                let userKey = each
                self.names.append(Name(nameTitle: snapFullname, nameDetail: snapUsername, userKey: userKey))
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                let avatarsRef = self.storageRef.child("avatars")
                let avatarRefByID = avatarsRef.child(each)
                avatarRefByID.getData(maxSize: 10*1024*1024) { (data, error) in
                    if data != nil {
                        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data!))
                        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
                        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                        self.banner = NotificationBanner(title: snapUsername,
                                                        subtitle: "Offers a friendship",
                                                        leftView: imageView,
                                                        rightView: nil,
                                                        style: .info,
                                                        colors: nil)
                        self.banner.show()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
    reqFriendsRef.observe( .childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let index = self.names.index(where: { $0.userKey == snapshot.key }) {
            self.names.remove(at: index)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 0.25) {
                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

i need a banner to be shown only when a new child node is added, not every time when i call my observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it. Now when i'm showing banner i do post a new value like  ["notified" : "true"] to a request and before showing banner i do check if its "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code to make a more thorough assessment, the first thing that comes to mind for caching your node is [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) if the data needs to persist indefinitely or [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache) if would be ok loosing the data in certain circumstances.